# How can I pull HTML code into an NSString from an iOS app?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios4

I am trying to pull down the code from an HTML website that has no more than 2 lines on it. The code contains a word that I need to retrieve. Is there a simple way to pull down that code and put it in an `NSString`?

**Further details:** I am going to have an app that checks for a word on a page. If that word is what I am looking for, the app will show the text "confirmed". The purpose of the app is to check to see if the page is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a http library to hit the server try [asihttp](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). Apart from this i need more info of what you are trying to do...

Comment: The App Details: I am going to have a app that checks for a word on the page if that word is what I am looking for then the app will show the "confirmed" text. The purpose of the app is to check to see if the page is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if that website is reachable, you can go with [HTTP Success Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success).

Using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) simplifies communication over the web.

---

If you still want to evaluate the text on that website, can also just retrieve it using:

[`[request responseString];`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#creating_a_synchronous_request)

Depending on what you get from the website, it's up to you how to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the link between the quotes and it'll work!

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {     
    NSString * sFeedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,270000,960000"];
 //RSS Feed URL goes between quotes
  NSString * sActualFeed = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sFeedURL] encoding:1 error:nil];
       NSLog(@"%@", sActualFeed);
}
```